# Multi store setup Magento maximum?

Tags: magento

I have setup a magento installation with a multi-store backup. However, lately we are dealing with some severe hosting/performance issues.

Everything is optimized for magento on the server-side and we are also using caching. However, especially when performing database-intensive operations (adding several products to the stores), we see that the performance of the server goes down.

I have been thinking what can go wrong and I guess it has to do with the number of stores we have on one back-end. In fact, currently 20 store-fronts are installed on the server.

Does anyone know whether there is a maximum in amount of stores that can be setup as multi-store on one Magento backend?

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer your basic question no there isn't a maximum amount of stores that can be run on a multi-store backend. This database intensive slowness is probably not directly relevant to the amount of stores but instead is a result of re-indexing of prices when saving a product.

Take a look at these links, there are some solutions on how to resolve this issue:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/221229/P0/
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/38818/P90/#t367525

Comment: magento changed they forums structure and no possible to read info from provided links.